# map over a function which is actually an array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

The problem is kind of easy to explain, lets say we have the following function:

```
const patterns = (item) => [
  `${item.name}/${item.familyName}`,
  `${item.name}${c.item.familyName}`,
  `${item.familyName}`,
];
```

I would love to map it and create an object which has both the result of the function + the line that originated it.

For example:

```
Item = { "Luis", "García" }
```

Expected output:

```
[
value: "Luis/García", pattern: `{name}/{familyName}`, 
value: "LuisGarcía", pattern: `{name}{familyName}`, 
value: "García", pattern: `{familyName}`
]
```

Pseudo code not working (of course)

```
patterns().map(x=> {return  {value:x(item)  pattern=x(translator) } }
```

Where translator is:

```
{name: "{name}", familyName: "{familyName}"
```

The second part seems right, the problem is that it seems not possible to do a for each of the function array.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the `patterns` const cannot be changed, then please realise there is nothing at runtime that holds the strings "name" and "familiyName", so their is no way they would pop up in your result. Template literals are evaluated when the function runs, and leave no trace about the template literals themselves.

Comment: That's the function of the translator. When you use it as the attribute for the function, you get a representation of the template literals used (of course not the real ones tho)

The problem here is that I can't find a way to split the function to do a for each or a map over it (over each template literal)

Comment: @LoïcV check my answer using eval() - This gets you what you want I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:

```js
const patterns = (item) => [
  `${item.name}/${item.familyName}`,
  `${item.name}${item.familyName}`,
  `${item.familyName}`,
];

const patternsArray = patterns({ name: '{name}', familyName: '{familyName}' });
const valueArray = patterns({ name: 'Luis', familyName: 'Garcia' });

const resultsArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
  resultsArray.push({
    value: valueArray[i],
    pattern: patternsArray[i],
  });
}

console.log(resultsArray);
```

Output:

```sh
[ { value: 'Luis/Garcia', pattern: '{name}/{familyName}' },
  { value: 'LuisGarcia', pattern: '{name}{familyName}' },
  { value: 'Garcia', pattern: '{familyName}' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited
Try this:

```
const patterns = (item) => [
  `${item.name}/${item.familyName}`,
  `${item.name}${item.familyName}`,
  `${item.familyName}`,
];

const patternMatcher = [
  {value:(item) => `${item.name}/${item.familyName}`, pattern: `{name}/{familyName}`},
  {value:(item) => `${item.name}${item.familyName}`, pattern:`{name}{familyName}`},
  {value:(item) => `${item.familyName}`, pattern:`{familyName}`},
];

const inputParam = {name:"Luis",familyName: "Garcia"}; 
const result = patterns(inputParam).map(resultItem => {
    const pattern = patternMatcher.find(obj => obj.value(inputParam) === resultItem).pattern;
    return {value:resultItem, pattern}
});
```

Comment: that would work also! But it's as well something that modifies the original patterns constant. I would love to find a solution not involving modifications on the patterns const.

Updating it would be ok tho

Answer (score 0):

One (ugly) way to do it, is to have the function as an array of functions at the begining:

const patterns =[
(item) => `${item.name}/${item.familyName}`,
(item) => `${item.name}${c.item.familyName}`,
(item) => `${item.familyName}`,
];

Then patterns.map works (without ())

But would love to be able to solve the problem without modifying the initial function!